# RecyclerView items disappearing after fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I'm using Navigation component Architecture in my application, the problem I have in fragment navigations, is that when I navigate to another fragment and click the back button the previous fragment recreating. it's not like navigating between activities that when user clicks back button the previews activity is exactly like where you left it.

in my case its a RecyclerView in a fragment that I set the adapter inside the onViewCreated.

and I have a click listener for RecyclerView items that navigate to another fragment. but when I click the back button, none of recyclerView Items are showing.

Comment: remove sethasfixedsize

Comment: @Zuhrain i did not use sethasfixedsize